# Download files and create the same folder structure as the Host

Tags: c#, file-io, download, directory

I have a config file which consists of list of URIs I want to download. For example,

```
  http://xyz.abc.com/Dir1/Dir3/sds.txt
  http://xyz.abc.com/Dir2/Dir4/jhjs.txt
  http://xyz.abc.com/Dir1/itr.txt
```

I want to read the config file and and copy each URL but at the same time create the same directory structure as on the host. For example, for the first line in the config file, I want to create the directory structure Dir1/Dir3 on my local machine (if it doesn't exist) and then copy sds.exe to .../Dir1/Dir3/

How do I do this in C#?

What I have till now is:

```
string myStringWebResource; //Read this from the config file
System.IO.StreamReader file =
new System.IO.StreamReader("config.txt");

// Read the config file line by line
while ((myStringWebResource = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Create a new WebClient instance.
    using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
    {
        //How do I keep the original filename, e.g. sds.txt
        string outputFilename = @"" + ???";

        Console.WriteLine("Downloading ...");
        // Download the Web resource and save it into
        // the current filesystem folder.
        try
        {
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, outputFilename);
            Console.WriteLine("Successful");
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fail" + e.Message);
        }
    }  
}
```

While this lets me download all the files in the config file,

1. I have this problem of having to name them after download, how can I retain their original name?
2. All the files get downloaded in the same folder. How could I replicate the folder structure from the Host?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would we to filter the host out. Then split each remaining string on the /. Then build a method that takes a string[] as argument to create the directory structure. Move the file with filename (last item in the array) in that directory, using the original path (without host).

If the host is variable, remove everything before the third /.

Comment: Thats nice. but can you please tell me how to filter out the host